# How to extented a git merge driver?

Tags: git, git-merge

I found this great example about how to implement a git merge driver:
https://github.com/Praqma/git-merge-driver

For saving some clicks, the idea is to create a merge script, changing the .gitconfig and change the .gitattributes to use it for some files.

**merge-driver.sh**

```
echo "ancestor: $1"
echo " current: $2"
echo "   other: $3"
echo "This is the merge result" > $2
echo "Conflict resolved!"
echo "resolved: $2"
cat $2
exit 0
```

**.gitconfig**

```
[merge "my-custom-driver"]
    name = Custom Driver
    driver = merge-driver.sh %O %A %B
```

**.gitattributes**

```
*.mrg merge=my-custom-driver
```

My problem is: I want to call Git default merge-driver before to solve the conflict, if does not exits correctly, then I can check the `<<< === >>>` conflicts and solve them if I can.

So, how does I call git default merge driver manually ?

Answer (score 2):

> ... how [can] I call git default merge driver manually?

You can't—not quite.  The problem is that the default merge driver is directly built into `git merge`, in the low-level merge handling.  Your alternatives are to invoke the built-in merge handling, or to invoke your custom driver, and if you've chosen your custom driver, the default merge handling alternative has already been rejected and is no longer available.

Luckily, there's a program built into Git that's almost as good as the default merge driver, or maybe even better (it has one option that the default driver lacks).  This program is named `git merge-file` and [it is documented](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file).  If you give it the right set of parameters, it will achieve pretty much the same thing *as* the default merge driver.

It will exit zero if it believes it has resolved the conflict, and nonzero if not.